# Divide a circle into segments in Titanium

Tags: titanium, line, geometry

I have drawn a circle in Titanium using the following code.

```
var wheelTop = Ti.UI.createImageView({
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        borderRadius: 50,
        borderColor: '#1a0033',
        backgroundColor: '#8400ff'
});
```

Now, I would like to divide this circle into 24 segments and create a separate property for each segment.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use a WebView containing an HTML canvas.

I've also read that the Raphaël js lib (http://raphaeljs.com/) using SVG can be included in Titanium:

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/15861/using-raphaeljs-js-drawing-library-in-a-mobile-app

If a webview is not an option, you could check out some modules in the marketplace:
https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/4967?1054292716
https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/5941?416198363